# Angular 6 router navigation giving error Cannot read property 'OVERWRITE'

Tags: angular6

I have migrated my angular application from Angular 5 to 6, when I am calling router navigation,

```
this.router.navigate(['doctor-log-in']).then(function (res) {
       console.log(res);
     }, function (err) {
       console.log('in errrrr');
       console.log(err);
     });
```

it's giving below error

> main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'OVERWRITE' of undefined at new n (main.9819f0c7d0ec0efd5341.js:1) at n.applyServerOverwrite

Answer (score 0):

Run below command to generate dist folder.

> npm run build --prod

instead of

> ng build --prod

then it's working.